# Query XML with multiple nodes of same name where node isn't always in same sequence

Tags: sql, xml, xquery

I have an XML with several nodes at the same level, I am trying to query the same elements each time, but sometimes the element could the the element[5] or element[6] or even 7 depending on what the user actually filled out

tried   `XMLData.query('//ticket/sections/section[@name="Incident"]/group[@id=25]/ticket-input[6]/values/value/enum_val/name')`

and several variations of it, but some records have the info in tiecket input[6] and others between 3 and 7, there is a unique 96 or 685 that identifies the correct node (so I can get to the sub nodes), but using below I cannot filter to it:

```
XMLData.query('//ticket/sections/section[@name="Incident"]/group[@id=25]/ticket-input/id=96/values/value/enum_val/name') 
    AS billing
FROM
  XMLwithOpenXML
```

XML Data:

```
    <section id="12" position="3" name="Incident" kind="Basic">
      <group id="58" name="Facility Location">
      </group>
      <group id="25" name="Incident Location">
<ticket-input>
  <id type="integer">93</id>
  <name>City</name>
  <data-type>enumerable</data-type>
  <data-option>single</data-option>
  <position type="integer">6</position>
  <flags type="array"/>
  <short-name nil="true"/>
  <values>
    <value id="8288834" client_id="">
      <enum_val>
        <name>cleveland</name>
      </enum_val>
    </value>
  </values>
</ticket-input>
<ticket-input>
  <id type="integer">91</id>
  <name>Address 1</name>
  <data-type>string</data-type>
  <data-option nil="true"/>
  <position type="integer">4</position>
  <flags type="array">
    <flag>allow_lowercase</flag>
  </flags>
  <short-name>Address 1</short-name>
  <values>
    <value id="8288832" client_id="">
      <formatted_string_val>123 rd</formatted_string_val>
    </value>
  </values>
</ticket-input>
<ticket-input>
  <id type="integer">260</id>
  <name>Location Name</name>
  <data-type>location</data-type>
  <data-option nil="true"/>
  <position type="integer">1</position>
  <flags type="array"/>
  <short-name nil="true"/>
  <values>
    <value id="8288835" client_id="">
<location>
  <id type="integer">9893</id>
  <kind>Hospital</kind>
  <name>HEALTHS</name>
  <address>123 rd</address>
  <address-2 nil="true"/>
  <city>cleveland</city>
  <state>OH</state>
  <zip>45632</zip>
  <phone></phone>
  <phone-2 nil="true"/>
  <fax nil="true"/>
  <fax-2 nil="true"/>
  <code>1701007</code>
  <location-group-id type="integer">16</location-group-id>
  <ticket-fields-count type="integer">14</ticket-fields-count>
  <disabled type="boolean">false</disabled>
  <location-fields-count type="integer">1</location-fields-count>
  <latitude>42° 22' N</latitude>
  <longitude>083°281' W</longitude>
  <location-type>Skilled Nursing Facility</location-type>
</location>
    </value>
  </values>
</ticket-input>
<ticket-input>
  <id type="integer">97</id>
  <name>State</name>
  <data-type>enumerable</data-type>
  <data-option>single</data-option>
  <position type="integer">7</position>
  <flags type="array"/>
  <short-name nil="true"/>
  <values>
    <value id="8288836" client_id="">
      <enum_val>
        <name>MI</name>
      </enum_val>
    </value>
  </values>
</ticket-input>
<ticket-input>
  <id type="integer">685</id>
  <name>Apartment, Suite, or Room</name>
  <data-type>string</data-type>
  <data-option nil="true"/>
  <position type="integer">5</position>
  <flags type="array">
    <flag>allow_lowercase</flag>
  </flags>
  <short-name>Apt/Suite</short-name>
  <values>
    <value id="8288833" client_id="">
      <formatted_string_val>12</formatted_string_val>
    </value>
  </values>
</ticket-input>
<ticket-input>
  <id type="integer">96</id>
  <name>Zip</name>
  <data-type>string</data-type>
  <data-option nil="true"/>
  <position type="integer">8</position>
  <flags type="array"/>
  <short-name nil="true"/>
  <values>
    <value id="8288837" client_id="">
      <formatted_string_val>48377</formatted_string_val>
    </value>
  </values>
</ticket-input>
```

on query 1 I can get the data on some records, but not in right sequence in others when not exact amount of "ticket items" are present. The second query will not filter on the actual text value.

Comment: Don't you get a syntax error on the part with`ticket-input/id=96/`? I think you want another predicate instead i.e. `ticket-input[id=96]/`.

Comment: Wow, yes totally lost my mind, I kept trying id[attribute::96] and others for some reason thinking the brackets were preserved for metadata only..